# When to use threadlocker?

Tags: vibration, bolts, corrosion, threadlocker, tightening-torque

Despite the use of threadlocker being somewhat widespread (e.g. repair videos), I have yet to see a single recommendation to use it in any service manual. Perhaps this is my relative inexperience, but I thought I'd ask the community out of curiosity - do you use threadlocker? If so, what is your criteria for deciding which bolts receive threadlocker and which ones do not?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the vehicle but it's not uncommon to see threadlocker specified for assembly.

Use threadlocker when it's called for.  Today many modern vehicles use one-time-only fasteners instead of threadlocker so it may be less common now than it was in the past.

I use threadlocker when the service manual says to, I replace fasteners when called for, and I just torque to spec when that is all that is specified.

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you're coming up with a correlation between using threadlocker and one-time-only fasteners?

Comment: I've known of some people who will reuse one-time fasteners and assume that if then just put threadlocker on them it will be ok.  That's NOT the case.  But some folks just do what they want.

Comment: One-time-fasteners are usually torque-to-yield, which don't use threadlocker.

Comment: @jwh20 Ahh ok. I guess it's just the cars I've worked on in which I've seen no mention of threadlocker in a manual.

Comment: @Paulster2 - Only other one-time fasteners I can think of are exhaust bolts/studs, but I also haven't seen threadlocker prescribed for those.

Answer (score 1):

The main places I have seen the required use of Threadlocker or Retaining Compound (e.g. Loctite 638) specified in a car repair manual is on the splines of driveshafts.

I have also seen a band of threadlocker already in place on new bolts that are used to hold brake callipers on.

[image]

Comment: Damn, well that makes it easy.